# C array pointer segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm not familiar to pointers and I stumbled upon segmentation fault on my code, wheres if I don't use pointers this code runs perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 

    char *string[100],i,j;
    char *(*odd)[100];
    i = j = 0;

    fgets(*string, 100, stdin);

    while (*string[i] != '\0') {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                *odd[j++] = string[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    *odd[j] = '\0';

    printf("Characters at odd position: %s\n",*odd[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm guessing that I'm printing the `odd` array the wrong way, but I can't print it just using `*odd` as well.

Comment: What does `*string[strlen(*string) - 1] = '\0';` do?

Comment: There are so many things wrong with that code that it's hard to know where to start. But *one* starting point might be this: Is `string` supposed to be a single string, or an array of strings? Right now it's the latter, an array of strings. Continue from there.

Comment: also `*string[strlen(*string) - 1] = '\0';` this line is a little bit strange => you want to be sure to have null character at the end of string (ie you don't be sure that you have one) and for that you use `strlen` which look for a null character....

Comment: @Garf365 I'm following this [link](http://see-programming.blogspot.my/2013/07/c-program-to-print-characters-at-even.html) but this is a non-pointer version. I wanted to convert it to full pointer version

Comment: the line `*odd[j] = '\0';` is important! you have to put null character at the end of odd string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZEOF_BUFFER 100

int main(){ 
    char *string; // string is a pointer
    char i,j;

    char *odd; // odd is a pointer

    // allocate memory to be able to store data
    string = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZEOF_BUFFER);

    if (string == NULL) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    odd = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZEOF_BUFFER);

    if (od == NULL) {
        free(string);
        exit(-1);
    }

    i = j = 0;

    fgets(string, SIZEOF_BUFFER, stdin);

    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                odd[j++] = string[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    odd[j] = '\0';

    printf("Characters at odd position: %s\n",odd);

    // Don't forget to free allocated memory
    free(odd);
    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```

Without pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){ 
    char string[100],i,j;

    char odd[100];

    i = j = 0;

    fgets(string, 100, stdin);

    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                odd[j++] = string[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    odd[j] = '\0';

    printf("Characters at odd position: %s\n",odd);

    return 0;
}
```

also, no need of `*string[strlen(*string) - 1] = '\0';` => `fgets` put always a null character at the end of string

Comment: this, this is awesome! it solves what I'm looking for, and reminds me of freeing allocated memory as well !

Comment: can i ask you another question? 
the main purpose of odd[j] = '\0'; as you said fgets always put a null character, after i assign to the new arrays pointer without using fgets, so they are without '\0', are my understanding correct?

Comment: You're partially right: you stop iterating on `string` when you find `\0` character, so you never put it in `odd`

Answer (score 2):

```
char *string[100],i,j;
fgets(*string, 100, stdin);
```

You are trying to write to address at `string[0]` but it is not initialized. I guess you mean smth like

```
char string[100];
fgets(string, 100, stdin);
```

P.S. `char *string[]` is an array of pointers to char while `char string[]` is an array of chars, and for this case in expressions `string` decays to pointer to first element i.e. to pointer to char.

Comment: cant i fgets into array of *string[100]?

Comment: `*string[100]` is an array of pointer, not an array of string, nor a string

Comment: So transform `char string[100]` to `char * string` and allocate memory (see my answer)

Comment: @ChristopherTan You can not since such array contain pointers, not chars. But you can receive string into buffer that is pointed to one of array elements, e.g. into `string[0]`: `fgets(string[0], ....)`. Note that this pointer must be properly initialized, i.e. it must point to valid buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with precedence of [] vs *. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence. To solve it do the dereferences like this:

```
(*odd)[j] = '\0';
```

This also applies to declarations; to declare string as a pointer to an array of 100 chars, change it to:

```
char (*string)[100];
```

You also must allocate memory. Here is a changed version of your code with all these changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char actualstring[100];
    char (*string)[100] = &actualstring, i = 0, j = 0;
    char actualodd[100];
    char (*odd)[100] = &actualodd;

    fgets(*string, 100, stdin);

    (*string)[strlen(*string) - 1] = '\0';

    while ((*string)[i] != '\0') {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                (*odd)[j++] = (*string)[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    (*odd)[j] = '\0';

    printf("Characters at odd position: %s\n",*odd);

    return 0;
}
```

You may find it useful to translate declarations to english and vice-versa at http://cdecl.org/

Comment: i changed to what u recommended two of the above but still segmentation fault (core dumped) occurs...

Comment: It's normal because you don't have allocated memory

Answer (score 0):

`string` is an array of pointers.  You did not initialize any of those pointers. But then you write through those pointers as if they pointed somewhere.

Your code is a more complicated version of:

```
char *ptr;
fgets(ptr, 100, stdin);
```

in which (hopefully) it should be obvious what the problem is.  `odd` has a similar problem.